# Linker can't find CTFontCreateWithNameAndOptions

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, linker, core-text

I am trying to use `CTFontCreateWithNameAndOptions()` from CoreText and the linker is saying "Symbol(s) not found", specifically for `_CTFontCreateWithNameAndOptions`. I added CoreText.framework and am importing <CoreText/CoreText.h>. It compiles fine, but the linker fails.

Here's the declaration in CTFont.h:

`CTFontRef CTFontCreateWithNameAndOptions(
    CFStringRef                 name,
    CGFloat                     size,
    const CGAffineTransform     *matrix,
    CTFontOptions               options ) CT_AVAILABLE_STARTING( __MAC_10_6, __IPHONE_3_2);`

Here's the actual call:

`CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithNameAndOptions( (CFStringRef)@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" , 14.0f , NULL , kCTFontOptionsDefault ) ;`

Anybody have any ideas?

My iOS app is linking against the 4.2 framework.

Comment: Apparently, it might not exist: http://friendfeed.com/bobtiki/5955ec13/for-those-with-fruit-company-bug-access-radar?embed=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. _CTFontCreateWithNameAndOptions is not part of the CoreText framework for iOS, it is part of CoreText framework for OS X only. I reported a documentation bug.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the CoreText.framework to your project.

1. Go to the project settings
2. Select the appropriate target
3. Click *Build Phases*
4. Expand *Link Binary With Libraries*
5. Click + to add, and find CoreText.Framework, as per screenshot:

[image: Add Core Text]

Comment: Nope, I'm fairly sure Apple only put it in the header and it's not in the library... which is why the linker is failing