# Error: "File was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s)"

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries, armv7

I have built my own Static C++ Library, which is built with the settings:

- Architectures: armv7, armv7s
- Build Active Architectures Only: No
- Support Platforms: iOS
- Valid Architectures: armv7, armv7s

The library project builds well and I got the .a file (I have cleaned the build folder and built the project again to be sure my settings were effective).

I have added the library (.a file) to my iOS project, but the project won't build even though I have set the exact same settings on the iOS project:

- Architectures: armv7s, armv7
- Build Active Architectures Only: Yes
- Support Platforms: iOS
- Valid Architectures: armv7, armv7s

I keep getting this error:

> **ld: warning: ignoring file** /Users/hidden/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloWorldCppLib-fomvvtklwijvqicyhahxleiscein/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libHelloWorldCppLib.a, **file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s):** /Users/hidden/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloWorldCppLib-fomvvtklwijvqicyhahxleiscein/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libHelloWorldCppLib.a

What am I missing? It tells me the .a file was not built for armv7s, but that is exactly the settings I built the library with.

Comment: you can check which architectures the library was built for running `lipo -info <library>` against its binary file.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303933/xcode4-linking-problem-file-was-built-for-archive-which-is-not-the-architecture

Comment: Jeez... another xcode landmine

Answer (score 33, accepted):

When you're building a library you must compile it both for the simulator and the device and then merge the two outputs (.a files) into 1 library and then link it to your iOS project.

Comment: That did the trick! I ran this in the terminal: `lipo -create libHelloWorldCppLibPhone.a libHelloWorldCppLibSimulator.a -output libHelloWorldCppLib.a` and imported the merged result to my iOS project.

Comment: I have created a script to simplify the merging process:
http://www.cupcakecoding.com/coding/fat-combine-script-for-static-libraries/

Comment: This worked for me! I'm still not sure why I need to compile it for both simulator and device when I only intend to run it on the device. Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 36):

I ran into a similar problem myself. `@graver`'s solution is definitely valid.

The issue was that the library was being built for `armv7` instead of `armv7s`. You can verify this yourself by using `lipo <path/to/lib.a> -info`.

Setting the `Build Active Architectures Only` option to `No` fixes the issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Library's 'Build Active Architectures' Release was YES, debug was NO. to YES fixed it.

Answer (score 23):

one additional notes is:

```
    Build Active Architectures Only  set to no
```

is for the lib project.

Comment: thanks. 
that was my problem when updating SDWebImage library

Answer (score 7):

I have got the exact same error when with cocapods :  For me the solution was to have two differents Build Active Architecture for target and pods.

App Target :

```
Build Active Architectures Only  **Yes**
```

pods Target

```
Build Active Architectures Only  **No**
```

Comment: This solved a problem that other solutions didn't 

Comment: it works wonderfully...cocoapods always come with new issues like this..

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately all these pieces of advice don't work for me - Xcode 7.3.1 (7D1014), iPhone 5.
but as soon as I removed all Xcode temporary files (+ restart Xcode) and rebuild again it became working.

Answer (score 1):

It did happen to me with Facebook SDK (v 4.24.0) used via CocoaPods.

Cleanning or setting `Build Active Architectures Only` to `NO` on Pods didn't resolve the problem.

The solution was to empty the build directory (see Build settings/Build locations/CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR) OR `$(CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR)` Xcode variable.

Comment: Note that this is in addition to everything shown in other solutions.  Worked for me on a cocoapods issue.

Answer (score 0):

I use XCode 5.1.1 and ran into the described problem. A more convenient way to solve this problem seems to be just to create an Archive (via menu Build/Archive) and distribute it. The distributed lib file will contain all defined architectures.