# Getting errors compiling an iOS App Using CorePlot 1.5.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, static-libraries, core-plot, linker-errors

So, I am trying to build and run an App on my iPhone 5 device. But "**suddenly**" (Was working fine until I ran `archive` to submit to iTunes connect) it is failing with errors. The app is using CorePlot graphing library and the error seems to be occurring in that library.

**So, the error is**

[image]

**Text**

> ld: warning: ignoring file
>   path/to/libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a,
>   file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked
>   (armv7):
>   path/to/libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a

I can understand the error. It basically says that the library was built not for armv7 architecture.

However, to confirm this I ran this **terminal command against the static library.**

```
lipo -info libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a
```

**and the result is,**

```
Architectures in the fat file: libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a are: armv7 armv7s i386 x86_64 arm64
```

I can't see a reason why this isn't running. The project compiles and runs on simulator but when I change to device it starts to fail.

**What have I tried so far?**

1. Seeking for solutions on Google - Failed
2. Cleaning project and running it again.
3. Quitting XCode and restarting it.
4. Shutting down Macbook and then restarting it.
5. Downloading [CorePlot 1.5.1](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/releases) source files and rebuilding the binary files.

After all above steps and many more. I have same error again and again. I don't know what am I done wrong.

---

**Environment Specs:**

- MacBook Pro running OSX 10.9.2
- XCode 5.1.1
- **Project > Build Settings > Architectures > Standard architectures (armv7, armvts, arm64)**
- **Base SDK > Latest iOS (iOS 7.1)**
- iPhone 5 with iOS 7.1.1

---

*If it helps, I am sharing the exact binary I am using right now with my app.*

- [CorePlot Binary which is being used.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63115907/CorePlot.zip)

---

Any idea about what am I doing wrong? I know there is like a silly mistake somewhere. But not sure where. Any extra info please comment. I will provide it straight away. I was about to upload my App to iTunes connect.

Comment: What about when you *Build it for Profiling*?  (I'm trying to determine if your *Release* Build Settings are broken, compared to your *Debug* Build Settings).

Comment: @trojanfoe , Yes it is failing if I build for profiling as well. I wanted to check core animation profiling for graphs so I wanted profile from my device. Thanks for the help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14828693/error-file-was-built-for-archive-which-is-not-the-architecture-being-linked-a