# Cannot ARC enabled cocos2d project

Tags: ios, cocoa, cocos2d-iphone, automatic-ref-counting

using Xcode 4.6.2.
Created an empty cocos2d iOS (ipad selected) project using cocos2d 2.0 rc1 (currently official site calls it unstable)

Exactly followed [this](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/04/enabling-arc-cocos2d-project-howto-stepbystep-tutorialguide/) step by step tutorial and keep getting this error:

> ld: warning: ignoring file
>   /Users/osx1/Desktop/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libcocos2dlib.a, file was
>   built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s):
>   /Users/osx1/Desktop/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libcocos2dlib.a Undefined
>   symbols for architecture armv7s:   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CCFileUtils",
>   referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CCSprite", referenced from:.......................

What should I do? Is this tutorial given link above some outdated?

Comment: I found answer here.It solved problem.[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303933/xcode4-linking-problem-file-was-built-for-archive-which-is-not-the-architecture)

Comment: In the tutorial you followed, it's important to read the first few comments afterword. I too get errors when converting to an ARC project, but usually it's the "Build Active Architecture Only" flag that messes it up.