# Linking C++ Static library in Xcode "Ignoring file, ..., was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)"

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, static-libraries

I'm having an issue including a C++ static library (.a) in my Cocoa Touch Static Library.

I'm getting a warning that `ignoring file /../libfileWrite.a, was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /../libFileWrite.a`

Later there are errors stating `Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_add", referenced from...`

**My Setup**

I have a fileWrite.cpp and fileWrite.h in a separate Xcode Cocoa Touch Static Library project.

fileWrite.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int add(int a, int b);
bool writeFile(const char* filePath);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

fileWrite.cpp

```
#include "fileWrite.h"

using namespace std;

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int add(int a, int b)
{
  return a+b;
}

bool writeFile(const char* filePath)
{
  ofstream file;
  file.open(filePath);
  if(!file)
  {
    return false;
  }

  file << "This is a test file write" << endl;
  file.close();
  return true;
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

I built my .h / .cpp project on the command line...

armv7

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project fileWrite.xcodeproj -target fileWrite -sdk iphoneos -arch armv7 -configuration Release clean build`

armv7s

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project fileWrite.xcodeproj -target fileWrite -sdk iphoneos -arch armv7s -configuration Release clean build`

i386

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project fileWrite.xcodeproj -target fileWrite -sdk iphonesimulator -arch i386 -configuration Release clean build`

...and built it into a fat file with lipo

`lipo -create -output libFileWrite.a libFileWrite-armv7.a libFileWrite-armv7s.a libFileWrite-i386.a`

`lipo -info libFileWrite.a`

returns

`Architectures in the fat file: libFileWrite.a are: armv7 armv7s i386`

Now, I took this static library and my single .h file and added it to my current project

Here is my current architecture setup.  (I changed the **Build Active Architectures Only** to **No** and changed the **Valid Architectures** to **i386 armv7 armv7s**

[image]

I made sure my library was part of the build phase and added a libc++ library too

[image]

The function that calls my **add** comes from a .mm file and it `#import "fileWrite.h"`

I just can't seem to get rid of this error:  `ignoring file /../libfileWrite.a, was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /../libFileWrite.a`

I tried adding **-lstdc++** to my **Other Linker Flags**,but had no luck.

[image]

I even tried toggling between these two options:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: have you tried all the steps here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303933/xcode4-linking-problem-file-was-built-for-archive-which-is-not-the-architecture

Comment: Yes, but with no luck.